# Undefined array key 1

Tags: php, laravel

Возникла ошибка при перезагрузке laravel страницы

```
   WARN  [Mon Jun 5 15:

  2023-06-05 15:11:10
   ErrorException

  Undefined array key 1

  at D:\OpenServer\domains\learnlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:310
    306▕             : '/^\[([^\]]+)\]/';
    307▕
    308▕         preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    309▕
  ➜ 310▕         return Carbon::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $matches[1]);
    311▕     }
    312▕
    313▕     /**
    314▕      * Get the request port from the given PHP server output.
PHP server output.

  1   D:\OpenServer\domains\learnlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:310
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\{closure}("Undefined array key 1", "D:\OpenServer\domains\learnlaravel\
vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php")

  2   D:\OpenServer\domains\learnlaravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:277
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::getDateFromLine("11:10 2023] 127.0.0.1:51171 Closing")
PS D:\OpenServer\domains\learnlaravel>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как устранить ошибку.

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/432695

Comment: Это значит что твой `preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);` __ничего не нашел__. А почему не нашел - тебе предстоит разбираться самому, так как никто не знает чему равен `$regex` и чему равен `$line`.

Comment: Уберите бесполезные скриншоты.. Напишите какая у вас ОС и какая версия laravel

Answer (score 0):

Судя по скриншотам, у вас версия windows меньше 11, и судя по исходным кодам версия laravel не ниже 9.

Похожая ошибка описана в тикете проекта laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/44282

Там разработчики сообщают, что laravel 9.x работает только под windows версии не ниже 11.

Таким образом необходимо либо обновить windows до версии 11, либо использовать более старую версию laravel.

Comment: Либо добавить 1 условие в код и всё будет работать